# Running R from terminal in ubuntu 16.04 gives Fatal Error message

Tags: r, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I just installed R 3.4.4 and Rstudio on my computer with the OS Ubuntu 16.04. Rstudio detects the Installation of R and works normally. However, trying to run R in the terminal I get this error:

> Fatal error: unable to open the base package

I have trying setting the R_HOME using:

> export R_HOME=/usr/lib/R

However it did not work. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: _How_ did you install R and where did you install it from?  R is native to Ubuntu, and `sudo apt-get install r-base` will always give you a working version.  Similarly, RStudio will always use a working version from the path, so this is indicative of your R installation being questionable.  Lastly, Ubuntu 18.04 is the current LTS version...

Comment: I have used [r-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-ubuntu-16-04-xenial/), the "Add R Repository" version. I did not quite understand your explanation about RStudio Could you elaborate more?

Comment: I suggest you subscribe to the [r-sig-debian mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian) and ask there. We are generally friendly over there.  This space may be a little too confined for it.

Comment: Please *subscribe* so that you can post. Before you confirm your subscription your posts will not go anywhere.